Tensorflow: metric has not yet been built error
I am encountering an issue while training a CNN model using Tensorflow for a multiclass classification task. When attempting to fit the model, I am getting the following traceback error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/main.py", line 182, in <module>
    model.fit(
  File "/app/models/cnn.py", line 55, in fit
    super().fit(train, validation, num_epochs, steps)
  File "/app/models/neural_network.py", line 85, in fit
    self._history = self._model.fit(
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/keras/src/trainers/compile_utils.py", line 357, in result
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot get result() since the metric has not yet been built.

The error seems to be related to a metric not being built before fitting the model.
Can someone explain to me why this error is occurring and how I can resolve it? I've searched through the Tensorflow documentation, but I did not find any hint on how to avoid this error. The code snippet that produces this error is the following one:
class NeuralNetwork:

    def __init__(self, name: str, classes, shape, batch_size: int = 32, logger: Optional[Logger] = None):

        # Define model parameters
        self._classes = classes
        self._shape = shape
        self._batch_size = batch_size

        # Define model name and output
        self._name = name
        self._output = 'results/{}.keras'.format(self._name)

        # Define logger
        if logger is None:
            self._logger = Logger(name=self._name, level='INFO').logger
        else:
            self._logger = logger.logger

        self._already_exists = False
        self._history = None
        self._metrics = Metrics(name=self._name, output_dir=self._output)

        # Load model if exists
        if os.path.exists(self._output):
            self._model = keras.models.load_model(self._output)
            self._already_exists = True
        else:
            self._model = Model()
    
  def fit(self, train, validation, num_epochs, steps: list):

        # Compile model
        optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
        self._model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])

        # Callbacks definition
        reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau( monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', mode='max',factor=0.1, min_lr=0.0000001, patience=5, verbose=1)

        early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_categorical_accuracy', mode='max',           patience=10,verbose=1, restore_best_weights=True)

        model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint( filepath=self._output,  monitor='val_categorical_accuracy',save_best_only=True, mode='max')

        # Fit model
        self._history = self._model.fit(
            train,
            steps_per_epoch=steps[0],  
            epochs=num_epochs,
            validation_data=validation,
            validation_steps=steps[1],  
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=[
                reduce_lr,
                early_stop,
                model_checkpoint
            ]
        )


For what concern the dataset creation, I am following quite standard procedure:
def dataset_creation(...):
        
    ...

    for i, dataset in enumerate([self._train, self._validation, self._test]):

            # Extraction of data indexes of from the dataframe
            indexes = [str(index) for index in dataset.index]

            # Extraction of labels from the dataframe
            labels = dataset[[''.join(['label_', str(s).lower()]) for s in self._encoder.classes_]].astype(int)

            # Creation of the dataset with indexes and label
            d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((indexes, labels))

            # Apply the loader function to each element of the datasets
            d = d.map(lambda index, label: (
                tf.numpy_function(self.loader, [index, input_size], tf.float32),
                label
            ), num_parallel_calls=self._cores)

            if i in [0, 1]:
                d = d.repeat()

            # Operations for shuffling and batching of the dataset
            if shuffle:
                d = d.shuffle(len(indexes))

            d = d.batch(batch_size=batch_size)
            d = d.prefetch(buffer_size=1)
    
    ...

Any insights or suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Hi @Khoenix,The error you're encountering, "ValueError: Cannot get result() since the metric has not yet been built," typically occurs when trying to access metrics before the model has been trained or compiled. In your code, you're compiling the model within the fit method, but you're also accessing metrics (reduce_lr, early_stop, model_checkpoint) before calling the fit method.
To resolve this issue, you should ensure that the model is compiled before setting up the callbacks.
